# Feature Oriented Programming - examples

Tags: design-patterns, apache-fop, software-product-lines

I read something about Feature Oriented Programing, but I miss use-cases and examples. Are there any techniques or patterns that are application of FOP?

Answer (score 1):

Information on *Feature Oriented Programming* (**FOP**) - also known as *Feature Oriented Software Development* (**FOSD**) - can be found here:

- [FOSD on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOSD)
- [Feature-Oriented Software Development Research](http://www.fosd.net/)

Use-cases are often found in the [*Software Product Line Engineering*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_product_line_engineering) (**SPLE**) community, where FOSD is one emerging field of implementation techniques.

Whitepapers and tutorials on practical application with commercial tools:

- [pure::systems](http://www.pure-systems.com/)
- [BigLever Software](http://www.biglever.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are still intrested in FOP, take a look at this site: http://wwwiti.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/iti_db/research/featureide/

FeatureIDE is a Eclipse-based IDE for FOP. It also brings some examples and tutorials.

[SPL2go](http://spl2go.cs.ovgu.de/) is a repository of software product lines developed with FOP.

If you need some literature take a look at [this book](http://www.springer.com/computer/swe/book/978-3-642-37520-0).

Answer (score -1):

I think you mean Feature Driven Development (FDD).

And there are many example, but a good start point is wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_Driven_Development

Comment: From a cursory look it appears that while both FDD and FOP deal in feature development, the later has a focus on modularity (being pluggable).